# editing the position of a shape in PowerPoint

Tags: python, python-pptx

```
from pptx import Presentation


prs = Presentation(my_file)
print(prs.slides[1].shape[0])
#out:
#<pptx.shapes.picture.Picture at 0x2295816cf98>
```

I need to loop through my shapes and assign a custom height, width and vertical position :

```
height = 7002000
width = 12193200
```

i have my height + width values which I can set via assignment `prs.slides[1].shape[0].height = height`

with a simple loop.

one thing I can't find is the attribute to set the shape's position on the page, chiefly the `Vertical Position`

my correct value is set to `-0.16cm` which I'm trying to replicate.

I thought it might be under `left` or `top` but my correct presentation returns a value of 0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can use the provided convenience measurements like this:

```
from pptx.util import Cm

shape.left = Cm(5.5)
```

Which saves you doing the arithmetic to English Metric Units (EMU) yourself.

Comment: Will defo be using this going forward. Other than merging ppts this is a complete project. Thanks scanny you are the man

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally - I had to use a combination of `top` and `left` on the shape attribute.

in my case I had to set my variables to

```
top = -57600
left = 0
```

I then access the shape method

```
for slide in prs.slides:
   for shape in slide.shapes:
       shape.left = left
       shape.top = top
```